# Launchers in the dock of Ubuntu MATE using the Mutiny appearance configuration vanish on reboot. How can this be addressed?

Tags: mate, dock, mutiny

Just as the title says. I have an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installation running the MATE desktop environment with the Mutiny appearance configuration (styled after Unity7). I can set launchers in the dock but they all vanish when I reboot. How might this be addressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `.desktop` launcher files to the directory `~/.local/share/applications`. It should now be possible to search for the launchers and drag them to the dock and they should be retained in the dock following a reboot.